# Image moments using SIMD library

Tags: simd-library

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate central image moments for some rectangular ROI
using SIMD library. I often use IPP library for such tasks, but I want to try SIMD as it's
much "lighter" library. According to SIMD documentation, function SimdGetMoments()
returns only spatial image moments. Also, there is no multiplication with pixel value,
which differs from image moments definition specified in IPP documentation:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-image-moments

Is there some workaround to get central image moments for some ROI in accordance with IPP image moments definition?

Comment: It will be better if you add this issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know recently added function [SimdGetObjectMoments](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__other__statistic.html#ga38eb71fc90753224e9309eb4681c1052) has functionality close to required specification.